# Overriding Resource Route in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-headers, url-routing

I am trying to override the route of a resource only for an option request. I need this to properly get Cross Domain photo upload requests.

routes.rb

```
map.resources :photos
map.connect '/photos', :controller => 'photos',
   :action => 'options_stuff', :conditions => {:method => :options }
```

photos_controller.rb

```
def options_stuff
    puts "got to options@!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    set_access_control_headers
    head :ok
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
end


def set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1000'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with'
    puts "headers are #{headers}"
end
```

However it never gets to the controller I need. What am I doing wrong?

Btw, I am following the following 2 articles about how to do it: http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2011/7/26/Responding-to-the-OPTIONS-HTTP-method-request-in-Rails-Getting-around-the-Same-Origin-Policy/3387

https://gist.github.com/832700

**Update**
After a lot of pain an agony I scrapped the controller idea, although it did work like the answer suggests. Instead someone recommended to use a before filter like so:

before set

```
before_filter :set_access_control_headers, :only => [:index]


def set_access_control_headers
  if !request.put? && !request.post? && !request.delete? && !request.get?
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1000'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with'
    puts "headers are #{headers}"

    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: The name of the action is wrong in your routes. Shouldn't it be options_stuff?

Comment: thanks fixed that. But that wasn't it

Comment: `printf` debugging in a controller is probably not the best way to do this, but at least you're excited about it.

Comment: @tadman more like yelling at my machine at that point :). My debugger was also having a bad day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe routes are prioritized from top to bottom, the top one being highest priority and the bottom one the lowest. So consider switching your routes like this :

```
map.connect '/photos', :controller => 'photos',
 :action => 'options_stuff', :conditions => {:method => :options }
map.resources :photos
```

Comment: The first definition has the highest priority. This is sadly the opposite of Ruby in general where the last one sticks.

Comment: thank you that works well. Now I am getting a double render since the resource is also trying to render: `ActionController::DoubleRenderError in OptionsController#options_stuff`

Comment: Not sure why you're calling `head` in that method. `render` with `:status` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah `head :ok` is similar to `render :nothing => true, :status => 200`, make your choice

Comment: Alright thanks guys I managed to figure it out :). And you are right about the head :ok too.